# if com listagem de array

Tags: php, array, if

Estou apanhando com uso de arrays, preciso verificar valores e tomar decisões dependendo do que encontrar na listagem.

```
id | volume_total | volume_entregue | volume_restante
 1      15               10                 5
 2      10               10                 0
```

Meu problema é o seguinte nesta listagem:

- Se todas as linhas de volume_restante for (zero), então

  ```
  $status = 'Todos Entregues'
  ```
- Se todas as linhas de volume_restante forem iguais a volume_total, então

  ```
  $status = 'Nenhum entregue'
  ```
- Se em uma linha volume_restante tiver (zero) e em outra linha volume_restante tiver um valor igual ou menor que volume_total, então

  ```
  $status ='Entrega Parcial'
  ```

Não consigo formular if´s nesse esquema.

```
<?php
include "mysql.php";

$id = 13;
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM ped_vendas_item WHERE id = '$id' ");

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    $volume_entregue[] =$r['volume_entregue'];
    $volume_total[] = $r['volume_total'];
    $volume_restante[] = $r['volume_restante'];
}

if ($volume_restante > 0 and $volume_restante == $volume_total) {
    $status = "Todos Entregues";
} elseif ($volume_restante == 0){
    $status = "Nenhum";
} elseif ($volume_restante > 0 and $volume_restante < $volume_total){
    $status = "Entrega Parcial";
}
```

Imagem abaixo, é pra ter uma noção como é a listagem.

Tipo: podem ser vários itens, onde alguns desses podem ser entregues ao cliente totalmente ou parcialmente ou até mesmo um item da lista não ser entregue. Preciso fazer o controle disso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse `id` na query é o id do pedido ou o id do item do pedido? Você quer saber se foi entregue o pedido todo ou separadamente de cada item?

Comment: Aproveite e nos diga o que está dando errado. O seu código não está pegando os status corretamente?

Answer (score 0):

As variáveis dentro do seu `while` não estão declaradas [fora do escopo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php) do `while`, logo, quando você para fazer as comparações elas são inicializadas e possuem valor `null`.

Mesmo se você declarar elas fora, você está passando valores para ela na forma de `array` usando o `[]` mas no seu `if` você acaba comparando com `int` sem indicar o índice do `array` usando `$volume_entregue[0]`.

Isto posto, você pode fazer a verificação se do `status` dentro do `while` que é bem mais fácil, ficaria assim:

```
$status = "Sem informações";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
    if $r['volume_restantes'] == 0) {
        $status = "Todos Entregues";
    } else if ($r['volume_total'] == $r['volume_restante']){
        $status = "Nenhum";
    } else {
        $status = "Entrega Parcial";
    }
}
```

---

Há também a possibilidade de você fazer essa verificação direto do `mysql`, a `query` seria assim:

```
SELECT pdi.id, IF(pdi.volume_restante == 0, 'Todos Entregues', IF(pdi.volume_total == pdi.volume_restante, 'Nenhum entregue', 'Entrega parcial')) as 'status' FROM ped_vendas_item pdi WHERE pdi.id = '$id'
```

E depois dentro do `while`, você substituiria os `if` por:

```
$status = $r['status'];
```

Particularmente, como são vários casos, eu sugeriria usar o essa `query` adicionando o restante dos parâmetros da tabela `ped_vendas_item`, assim você apenas teria o trabalho de listar o resultado da `query` em vez de colocar vários `if` para descobrir o `status`.

Answer (score 0):

Estou fazendo assim. 
Só não sei como resgatar isso.

```
include "mysql.php";

$ped_venda_id = 13;


$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT pvi.ped_venda_id, IF(pvi.volume_restante ==0, 'T', IF(pvi.volume_total == pvi.volume_restante, 'N', 'P')) as 'status' FROM ped_vendas_item.pvi  WHERE ped_venda_id = '$ped_venda_id' ");  



while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $status = $r['status'];

}

echo $status;
```

Comment: Use o link de edição da pergunta, essa é uma resposta.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar com este código acima?